# Font Awesome Icon in Search Box Not Loading

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, icons

So I am developing a site at http://www.johnkimwell.com/Vetel/ and one problem I have is that the font awesome icon is not loading and is only showing a square. I checked everything including the css and I dont see any possible conflict.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Strange, indeed. I checked out your website and I found out that you are using FA v. 4.2.0, most of my websites use 4.7.0 so before doing anything else, replace your link element for font-awesome.css for this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Perhaps you are using a too old version. Other than that, I checked your headers, console log, everything seems fine.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `.fa::before` class from Font Awesome appears to be overridden by simple-line-icons. I unchecked the first property in the image below, causing the search icon to be displayed. If you are not using simple-line-icons, the easiest fix would be to get rid of

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">`

[Image of how I fixed the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxGbD.png)